# SQL trigger, update bit field based on current- and end time evaluation

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Edit since the goal of this seems to be unclear]

Consider the following data (not necessarily table):

```
| currentDate (day of query) | expiryDate  |isOK |
|----------------------------|-------------|-----|
| 25.01.2018                 |26.01.2018   |True |
| 24.01.2018                 |23.01.2018   |False|
```

Explantation for above data / entries:

On 25.01.2018 we check if the machine is still ok. Ideally the "isOk" field should simply be set to "True" by the database.
If on 24.01.2018 we check "isOk", it should have been set to False by the DB.

The overall goal is:

- To enter an expiry date for each piece of equipment.
- Every day the DB will perform an update on the "isOK" field and set it based on today's date and the expiry date.
- To have one field that will be set automatically by the DB through a daily query/job in order to get the isOk field.

Of course this could also be achieved programmatically:

- Basically the difference between expiry date and current date must always be >=1 otherwise we consider the machine qualification expired.

In addition it could be nice to have another calculated column showing how many days left before expiry, updated the same way as the "isOk" column.

Is this doable? If yes, SQL code would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the isOk column to be changed according to the Value changes in todayDate and EndDate columns, Make the isOk filed a Calculated field based on the other 2 columns

Suppose you Want the isOK Field as True if EndDate within 1 Week on todayDate. You may try this

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
  TodayDate DATE,
  EndDate DATE,
  IsOk AS (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,EndDate,TodayDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 7 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END)
)

INSERT INTO MyTable(TodayDate,EndDate)
SELECT GETDATE(),GETDATE()+10
UNION
SELECT GETDATE(),GETDATE()-10
UNION
SELECT GETDATE(),GETDATE()+7
UNION
SELECT GETDATE(),GETDATE()-7

SELECT
    *
    FROM MyTable
```

My Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please share some SQL code for this? I l am not clear on how to express this in MSSQL. I guess something like isOK AS (datediff(hour,startDate,enddate)). But how to "return/set" the required true or false?

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution. I updated the question and I hope that what I would like to achieve is now clearer.